# get the numpy index for a given image location

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

Given an image, are there any ways to let user interactively knows its location by pointing to a specific image location. For instance, when I point to the location with angle, what are the corresponding index of the numpy array used to represent this image.

[image]

Comment: Hans's answer is perfect if you want the user to tell your program where something is. If you mean you want your program to tell the user where something is, you could draw an unfilled red rectangle around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a [`MouseCallback`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gab7aed186e151d5222ef97192912127a4) function to any window generated with OpenCV. Following is a short example code derived from [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/09/capturing-mouse-click-events-with-python-and-opencv/) blog post. An image is shown in some window, and when the left mouse button is clicked, the `x, y` coordinates are printed. (That's how I understood your question.)

```py
import cv2

# Actual mouse callback function
def print_coords(event, x, y, flags, param):

    # If left mouse button is clicked, print image coordinates
    if (event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN):
        print([x, y])

# Read an image
image = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Set up window and mouse callback function
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", print_coords)

# Loop until the 'c' key is pressed
while True:

    # Display image; wait for keypress
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # If 'c' key is pressed, break from loop
    if  key == ord("c"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Some mouse clicking inside the window then gives such outputs:

```
[158, 239]
[63, 6]
[9, 18]
[59, 101]
[128, 279]
[298, 249]
```

Now, of course, you can do whatever you want inside the mouse callback function. Pay attention, if you eventually need global variables.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi HansHirse, thank you for the answer. If I want to output the pixel value along with each coordinate, how to modify your function? Thanks.

Comment: @user288609 Assuming you have a grayscale image, just change the `print` command inside the `print_coords` function to `print([x, y, image[y, x]])`.